# Automatic file upload to a Discord channel

Tags: node.js

So I'm trying to write a Discord selfbot (e.g. a bot that uses your token to write stuff from your own Discord account), using a Discord.js npm module and so far I'm doing this only for purpose of writing stuff every set interval of time.

I've successfully managed to get it to spam random words (using random-words npm module) and also the contents of a certain text file by lines. The final stage is getting it to upload random files within a certain folder to that channel, every set interval of time. How do I do that?

My code so far (token values and server/channel ids are hidden, naturally :P)

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "";

const bot = new discord.Client();

var fs = require("fs")
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("text.txt", "utf8");
fileContent=fileContent.split("\n");
var ind=0

bot.on("ready",()=>{
    console.log("Ready!");
    var server = bot.guilds.find("id","")
    var chan = new discord.TextChannel(server,{"id":""});
    bot.setInterval(()=>
    {
        chan.send(fileContent[ind%fileContent.length]).then(msg=>{
            console.log(msg.content); ind++;
        });

    },5000);
})

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

The current text file content sending feature doesn't have to stay. In fact, ideally I'd only like the bot to have an automatic file upload feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob library to find the list of all files in a specified folder, and then
From 
[Discord.js - stable release - textChannel#send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)
you send files by

```
var glob = require("glob")

glob("*", {cwd: __dirname + "/folder"}, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // er is an error object or null.
  channel.send({
    files: files.map(filePath => ({
      attachment: filePath,
      name: "whateveryouwant"
    }))[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
})
```

Comment: Okay, but that's how you send a specific file. How do I send a random file from a specified folder?

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)